# final condition for PDE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

This is kind of a general question. Can someone give an example of solving a boundary-value-problem, say a diffusion equation PDE in 1-D, where there is a final condition involving an indicator function? I'm trying to imagine how this would work in this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the coefficients are constant (or $C^{\infty}$) then, starting with any reasonable object (say an element in a Sobolev space), then the foward solution is smooth, so to end up with a non-sooth function you might have to consider very wild initial conditions, i.e.: I doubt one can wrte down the object you ask for.